# What css property controls the color of project name at the top of the sidebar in readthedocs

Tags: html, css, themes, sidebar, read-the-docs

I am trying to customise the search box in my readthedocs documentation. I managed to change the background color by setting in a custom css file:

```css
.wy-side-nav-search, .wy-nav-top {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

I haven't found though what property controls the color of the project name that displays right above the logo on this sidebar.

Thanks

Comment: Got a link to the page, or otherwise an HTML snippet?

Comment: It is not this one but it is similar - https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html# - The text would be the `Read the Docs` on the top of the sidebar

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I misread your comment. That text seems to be an image, in that case you should be looking to stylize the logo image. https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-change-the-color-of-png-image-using-css.html. In the case you manage to replace the image with text, you can do `.logo {color: your-color-here;}`

Comment: No luck, that one changes the main title (`Read the Docs Sphinx Theme`)

Comment: Updated the comment, I misinterpreted your intentions. My bad.